# Make a new column with values according to other columns - in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Taking this dummy data for example

```
structure(list(Metastasis_Brain = c("1", "1", "0", "1", "0", 
"0"), Metastasis_Liver = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0"), Metastasis_Bone = c("1", 
"1", "0", "1", "1", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Patient_1", 
"Patient_2", "Patient_3", "Patient_4", "Patient_5", "Patient_6"
))
```

Example of what I'm searching for: If there is `1` in columns `Metastasis_Brain` and `Metastasis_Liver`, the new column will contain `"Brain, Liver"`.

If all three tissues are `1`, then that row in the new column will contain `"Brain, Liver, Bone"`.
If all are `0`, then it doesn't matter, `NA` would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df  %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  left_join(pivot_longer(.,-rowname, names_prefix = '.*_') %>%
  filter(value>0) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  summarise(nm = toString(name)))

   rowname Metastasis_Brain Metastasis_Liver Metastasis_Bone                 nm
1 Patient_1                1                0               1        Brain, Bone
2 Patient_2                1                0               1        Brain, Bone
3 Patient_3                0                1               0              Liver
4 Patient_4                1                1               1 Brain, Liver, Bone
5 Patient_5                0                1               1        Liver, Bone
6 Patient_6                0                0               0               <NA>
```

in Base R you could do:

```
aggregate(ind~rn, subset(transform(stack(df), 
         ind = sub('.*_', '', ind), rn = rownames(df)), values>0), toString)

         rn                ind
1 Patient_1        Brain, Bone
2 Patient_2        Brain, Bone
3 Patient_3              Liver
4 Patient_4 Brain, Liver, Bone
5 Patient_5        Liver, Bone
```

Answer (score 0):

**base**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  row.names = c("Patient_1","Patient_2","Patient_3","Patient_4","Patient_5","Patient_6"),
  Metastasis_Brain = c("1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0"),
  Metastasis_Liver = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0"),
  Metastasis_Bone = c("1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0"),
  res = c("Brain, Bone","Brain, Bone",
          "Liver","Brain, Liver, Bone","Liver, Bone",NA)
)

df$res <- sapply(apply(df, 1, function(x) gsub("Metastasis_", "", names(df)[x == 1])), toString)            
df
#>           Metastasis_Brain Metastasis_Liver Metastasis_Bone                res
#> Patient_1                1                0               1        Brain, Bone
#> Patient_2                1                0               1        Brain, Bone
#> Patient_3                0                1               0              Liver
#> Patient_4                1                1               1 Brain, Liver, Bone
#> Patient_5                0                1               1        Liver, Bone
#> Patient_6                0                0               0                 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>